# postgres with inheritence with reference to same column/field

Tags: postgresql

First of all I'm new to postgres

Let's say we have a parent table called `module` and two tables that extend that table called `debtor` and `creditor`

Then we have a table called `accounting` which has a column called `module_id`. Is it possible for that column to refer with a foreign key to both `debtor` and `creditor`? They share the same parent table

I already use this data model in mysql

In the `accounting` table you only join common columns from the `module` table and never columns from `debtor` or `creditor`

```
module:
------------
id int
module_id_ int
name varchar

debtor (extends module):
------------
delivery_address varchar

creditor (extends module):
------------
bank_account varchar

accounting:
------------
id int
account_id int
type_offset int
accountoff_id int
moduleoff_id int (can either refer to debtor or creditor)
amount numeric(11,0)
```

When doing joins on `accounting` only common columns from `module` are used

Comment: Yes you can, a single column can have multiple foreign keys on it. And this FK can refer to different tables. However, I'm not sure if you really want this, it's an unusual datamodel. Even inheritance isn't widely used, I would not recommend to start with this when you're new to PostgreSQL. Try 3NF first, the rest comes later.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I think what the OP means is a foreign key where the `module_id` is pointing to *either* a `debtor` or a `creditor`, not two foreign keys where the column points to *both* tables

Comment: @Bergi The value must be present in both tables, for each foreign key. That's exactly why I'm having doubts about the datamodel.

Comment: @Bergi yes exactly.. is that possible? I already use this model in mysql, but of course then you have some columns which are only used in `debtor` which is null in `creditor` and vice versa

Comment: In this case you never join any data in the `accounting`  table from either `debtor` or `creditor` (except common data from `module` table)

Comment: @clarkk Using a single table, with some empty cells depending on the subtype of the row, enforced using a check constraint that it's either a debtor or a creditor and not both, is the cleanest way forward. Postgres does not allow foreign keys to reference any one of multiple tables, and does not enforce unique constraints across tables either, which is why table inheritance is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @Bergi ok, so what you are saying is that you should avoid using inheritence at all in postgres?

Comment: @clarkk [Yes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS). You say you were using it in mysql, does it not have those caveats there?

Comment: @Bergi mysql does not support inheritence which is why I consider using postgres instead for a new project. I'm now wondering if it's just better to stick with mysql because it's faster with read operations and in general less complicated